# Enable only current week days in Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I want to enable only current week days in Bootstrap date picker and I want to disable all remaining days.

I have try below link but it's not for current week.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,2,3,4,5,6]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vj77M/124/

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you asked, but here is how I managed to do this, maybe can help someone else:

Input for calendar:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date pickWeek'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the script (for my use, I had to disable sundays and set locale to pt-br):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.pickWeek').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'pt-br',
            format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
            sideBySide: true,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0]
        });
        $('.pickWeek').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().startOf('week'));
        $('.pickWeek').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(moment().endOf('week'));
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/as8033qy/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this
HTML part

```
<input id="dateID" type="date" />
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dtToday = new Date();
        var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dtToday.getDate();
        var minday = dtToday.getDate() - 7;
        var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
        if (month < 10)
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        if (day < 10)
            day = '0' + day.toString();
        var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
        var minDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + minday;
        $('#dateID').attr('max', maxDate);
        $('#dateID').attr('min', minDate);
    </script>
```